# Error propagation formulation for intrinsic or implicit randomness

Tags: notation, measurements, error-analysis

I have a question about how to formulate an equation with implicit uncertainties for error propagation, i.e. a quantity $y$ that is determined by input values $x$ and $t$ but also has its own intrinsic uncertainty.

Specifically, I want to estimate the uncertainty of the vertical position, $y$, of an object (a string "parallel" to the $x$ axis) in space at time $t$ and horizontal location $x$. The vertical position is identified by processing image frames taken from a video recording.

To observe the position we identify the pixel location of the object $(x^p, y^p)$ in a given frame where pixel edge lengths are $s$.
For the first frame we set the coordinate system such that $(x=0,y=0)$ is at the corner of the image. The camera and the origin are then assumed to be at rest with respect to each other up to "noise" in the movement of the experimental apparatus.

(In case it's helpful I effectively assume means that the true location of the corner of the image is $x(0, t)= 0 \pm \delta_x, y(0, t)= 0 \pm \delta_y$ where $x(i, t)$ denotes the spatial location of the i-th column ($y(i,t)$ row) of pixels in the image at time $t$.)

So for a given frame captured at time $t$ the calculated position at the $(x^p, y^p)$ pixel is impacted by uncertainty of the exact shift of the coordinate system and the exact time at which the frame was captured.

Now I am interested in the the height of an object at a specific $x$ location corresponding to $x^p$ in the first image. Let $x^p$ and $y^p$ denote the pixel coordinates of where the object appears in the image.

<strike>I determine $y(x,t) = s \cdot y^p$ where $y^p$ is found by traversing the pixels at $x^p=[x/s]$, rather $x$ is inferred as $x^p \cdot s$ and held constant, but of course the horizontal position $x$ corresponding to a fixed $x_p$ may vary through the measurement.</strike>

So abusing notation, I calculate the position of the object as $y(x,t) = s \cdot y^p$. Now there is uncertainty in $y^p$, $x^p$ and the time of the frame, but my equation only explicitly depends on $y^p$.

I can write $y^p(x^p, t)$ to emphasize that though I evaluate at specific pixel location $x^p$ and frame time $t$ these have some uncertainty $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_t$. But beyond identifying the exact horizontal position and the timing, there is some uncertainty about $y^p$ itself that is due imaging limitations.

It makes sense to me to write $y^p(x^p, t, e) = y(x^p,t) + e$ where $e$ is an intrinsic error term, then I have the following terms:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial y^p}{\partial x^p} &\propto y^p(x^p+1) - y^p(x^p)  \\
\frac{\partial y^p}{\partial t} &\propto y^p(x^p,t) - y^p(x^p,t)\\
\frac{\partial y^p}{\partial e} &= 1\\
\frac{\partial y^p}{\partial s} &= y^p\\
\end{align*}
dropping dividing by the step size for fractions for the finite differences.

So assuming the variance in $x^p$, $t$ and $e$ are independent we have
\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{Var}(s \cdot y^p) = s^2 \left\{(y^p(x^p+1) - y^p(x^p) ) \sigma_{x}^2 + (y^p(x^p,t) - y^p(x^p,t)) \sigma_t^2 + \sigma_e^2 \right\} + (y^p)^2 \sigma_s^2
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{Var}(s \cdot y^p) = s^2 \left\{\frac{\partial y^p}{x^p}^2 \sigma_{x}^2 + \frac{\partial y^p}{\partial t}^2 \sigma_t^2 + \sigma_e^2 \right\} + (y^p)^2 \sigma_s^2
\end{equation*}
The problem is that for most error propagation it's thought of as an input out function $f(a,b,c)$, so I measure $a$, $b$ and $c$ and put these through $f$, but $e$ is not measured, I just treat it as $e=0$ except for calculating the derivative. Is there a more coherent/consistent way to write up this sort of error propagation? I guess the point is that $f$ itself is in this case implicitly "stochastic" with $e$ being a random variable.

An alternative approach would be to think of taking the derivative with respect to the $y$ position, $\frac{\partial y^p}{\partial y^p}=1$ and just multiplying this by $\sigma_e$, however, this also feels a bit strange as $y^p$ is just $y^p$.

Comment: This is very confusing. What is $y(x, t)$? Do you mean $y(x(t))$? What is a frame? Is the independent variable $t_i \pm \delta t_i$, from which $x_i \pm \delta x_i$ and $y\pm \delta y_i\pm e_i$ are determined? Where $i$ labels the measurement and $e_i$ is an unknown realization of a random varibale. From which you seek a relation $y = f(x)$

Comment: Thanks for reading. I tried to edit it a bit to clarify. Essentially I'm analyzing a movie and I assume that the image frame is "fixed" in space but might have small shifts due to imaging aberrations and vibrations in the experimental apparatus. I focus on a fixed $x$ position corresponding to a given pixel in the initial state. Then I'm tracking the motion of a string up or down at this point. Yes, you could think of subscript $i$ as corresponding to  a specific frame from the movie.